# How to handle Antlr.RunTime.InputMismatchException?

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have project that parses a2l files using Antlr. Here are two of my parser rules:

```
...
enumMemSegmMem      : enumMemSegmMem_ = ( EEPROM
                        | EPROM
                        | FLASH
                        | RAM_VALUE
                        | ROM_VALUE
                        | REGISTER
                        | NOT_IN_ECU)
...                                     ;
subGroup        : BEGIN_SUB_GROUP
                (identifier += IDENT )*
              END_SUB_GROUP
...
```

Here are some of my lexer rules:

```
...
BEGIN_SUB_GROUP     : BEGIN WS 'SUB_GROUP'
            ;
...
END_SUB_GROUP       : END WS 'SUB_GROUP'
            ;
...
RAM         : 'RAM'
            ;
ROM         : 'ROM'
            ;
...
IDENT           : WORD_CHAR [a-zA-Z0-9_.[\]]*
            ;
...
WS          : [ \t\r\n]+        -> skip
            ;
fragment WORD_CHAR  : [a-zA-Z_]
            ;
```

When I have something like  `BEGIN SUB_GROUP RAM END SUB_GROUP`, I get Antlr4.RunTime.InputMismatchException.

I would like the project to continue parsing when an Identifier is also find as a string literal within lexer rules and also to show the exception.

I tried to put the IDENT rule above all rules in lexer rules, but I don't want all the words to be matched there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because ANTLR will not create an `IDENT` token for the input "RAM". Such input ("RAM") will always become a `RAM` token.

If you want to let such keywords also be matched in the parser as an identifier, you need to do something like this:

```
subGroup
 : BEGIN_SUB_GROUP ident* END_SUB_GROUP
 ;

ident
 : IDENT
 | BEGIN
 | END
 | RAM
 | ROM
 // more keywords here?
 ;
```